# Unable to start jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When i try to run jupyter it shows me this error :-

> ERROR: the notebook server could not be started because no available port could be found.

Terminal Logs are as follows:-

```
[I 20:52:08.747 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 20:52:08.748 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 20:52:08.748 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 20:52:08.749 NotebookApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 20:52:08.750 NotebookApp] The port 8892 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 20:52:08.750 NotebookApp] The port 8988 is already in use, trying another random port.
[C 20:52:08.779 NotebookApp] ERROR: the notebook server could not be started because no available port could be found.
```

And, I also checked my system to check which process is running on that port and I found that no process is running and none of these ports are used by any process. But, I still get that error.

[image]

I also changed a default port of jupyter to various other port, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem then run with

```
jupyter notebook --port 9999
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me `jupyter notebook stop 8888` or
`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888`
I found solution [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3495#issuecomment-418883536)

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds silly, but I've just run into this problem and restarted my OS, and the error was gone!

Comment: Same here. Just rebooted my Win10 machine and it works, no issues. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The error may not be cause by jupyter, but your system.

To clear this, you can try open a simple http server on port 8888 and see whether the failed message is the same.

You can try one of the following commands to start a http server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 (Python2)
python -m http.server 8888  (Python3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I once have met this. It is because your interpreter. The version interpreter of your current project is not suitable for your anaconda. You can change your interpreter and then connect jupyter. That may be helpful. (:D

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple in Ubuntu and WSL:

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root --port 9999
```